# Excel Query to Append Repeated Columns into New Table As Records

Tags: microsoft-excel, query, power-query

I have a Microsoft Forms that customers fill out. The same three questions are asked multiple times as they have to answer the same three questions for multiple parts. What ends up happening when I get this data in excel is a table with a ton of columns such as:
PartNo, Qty, Cost, PartNo2, Qty2, Cost2, PartNo3, Qty3, Cost3, etc.

I need to export this data into a database for further use, and what I would like to do is group the PartNo, Qty, Cost into a separate table.

To do this my approach that I believe will work is some sort of Power Query that takes in these columns along with the ID and append them to a new table with the columns: ID, PartNo, Qty, Cost

Example:

Table from MS Form:
ID | Name  | PartNo | Qty | PartNo2 | Qty2 | PartNo3 | Qty3
3  |  Bob  |   344  |  3  |   243 | 7 | 112 | 1

What I would like:
ID | PartNo | Qty
3  |    334 |    3
3  |    243 |   7
3  |    112 |    1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your cursor in the respondent-case table (the flat table).

Use Home>Get & Transform Data>From Table/Range, so you get this:

[image]

Now select all columns starting from PartNo onwards, then use Transform>Any Column>Unpivot Columns>Unpivot Only Selected Columns, so you get this:

[image]

Now right-click Attribute and use Split Columns>By Non-digit to digit:

[image]

Now you should have this:

[image]

Now right-click Attribute.2 and use Replace Values. Value to find = null, Replace with = 1.

Now click the ABC icon at the top of Attribute.2 and change the data type to Whole Number. At this point you should have this:

[image]

Now select Attribute.1 and use Transform>Any Column>Pivot Column. Configure the dialog like this:

[image]

When you click OK, you'll get the desired output. You can optionally remove or rename Attribute.2.

[image]

You can then use Home>Close & Load to load the result to your workbook.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you so much!